# Can I cluster a SQL SERVER 2012 table on a column that's not the primary key?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Content (
            [ContentId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
            [Title] NVARCHAR (50) Not NULL,
            CONSTRAINT [PK_Content] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ContentId] ASC)
        )";

CREATE NONCLUSTERED UNIQUE INDEX Content_Subject_IX On Content (Title)
```

I understand that it's best to have the primary key as an identity key and to have the
table clustered on that (is that correct) ?

However for performance reasons I want to have a very fast access of the table with
something like a

```
SELECT FROM CONTENT WHERE TITLE = "overview"
```

Can I have my primary key as ContentId and still cluster the table on Title for the fastest access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you can create a cluster index on non parimary key.
If your Title column is unique then only creating cluster index on this will help.

Moreover if your Content table is being referred by other tables than not havign cluster index on primary key will hur performance for joins.

You will be better served if you keep your table as it is.

Whatever you decide do a performance testing to validate it.

Comment: I know this is slightly off topic but if I leave as is and it uses the index to access the rows in my content table is any of that index information store in memory with SQL Server 2012? I think I remember reading that Oracle stores it's most recently used information and in Oracle I can have some tables/indexes stored in memory.

Comment: @Melina SQL server has similar features. Let it handle it. Do optimizations only when you do perf testing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can separate the clustered index from the primary key constraint; however, to minimize fragmentation for high insert tables, I would recommend that you cluster on a monotonically increasing column.  For low-insert tables, this is less of an issue.

Comment: Thanks - Can you tell me if I do make the clustered index on the title column then will that be quicker access for the select in my question than if I create an index on Title for the table?

Comment: It depends on how it's being used, how much data is being stored, and how the data is distributed.  Short answer: I can't tell you based the limited amount of information we can share here.